How to connect a switching power supply to a converter with 2 inputs and a BMS?
I am building a circuit for an EV with a capacitor and need help connecting the switching power supply with the BMS and converter (The highlighted part). The switching power supply needs to be connected to the converter but it needs 2 inputs (+ and ground/-).
How can I also connect the negative to C- on the BMS?
Do I just connect a + and − to the converter and then have a - wire to the BMS?
BMS Specifications:
Continuous Discharge Current: 35A
Momentary Discharge Current: 100A
Charge Voltage: 54.6V
Charge Current: 8A(Max.)

PS:

Step-up converter:


What is the intention where connecting both input&output of a step-up converter to the same battery? And a rheostat permanently connected to the power rails, at that.

I can't find any justification for the two top-left converters. A supply of charging power would indeed be connected to the charge input(s) of a BMS.

I am not sure how to answer these comments. Sidenote; I did not design this circuit, a previous team did and I am just trying to follow their schematic and seeing if it works.
